# CodeIgniter URI routing: remove route segment from base URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

How do I remove a route segments from my base URL? For instance, I have these routes in my **routes.php**:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main_controller';
$route['users'] = 'user_controller';
$route['user/(:num)'] = 'main_controller/user/$1';
```

They all get routed normally, but in the view called by the 
`user()` method all of the generated links (for `.js`, `.css`, `.png` files, etc...) have `user/` inserted betweem base URL `localhost/domain_name` and file path (e.g. `css/style.css`), so all of those links (as you would expect) return `404` and the page isn't formatted properly.

If you need more info on the code in question, just comment what you need and I'll add it. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** If it's any help, `echo base_url();` in the view prints out  `http://localhost/domain_name/`.

Comment: In view file, call absolute path (i.e. `/css/style.css`).

Comment: @Tpojka But now it doesn't prepend the base URL automatically?

Comment: @StefanStanković - yes it won't, but does it work?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Still `404`...

Comment: You have to set scheme prepended and also forward slash at the end in base url (i.e. `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/domain_name/`).

Comment: @Tpojka But all the other pages work perfectly, adding the required `http://localhost/domain_name/` automatically, it's just that once I invoke a method through routing, the URL changes to `http://localhost/domain_name/user/css/style.css` instead of `http://localhost/domain_name/css/style.css`

Comment: Have you set it and tried? You shouldn't experience issue with base_url correctly set.

Comment: @Tpojka I have, before posting the question, and after you asked me to. The mapped URL still has `user/` in it. None of the SO questions and answers seem to cover this specific problem...

Comment: This is one your comment: `$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/domain_name';` which is not even close what I asked after seeing your comment. I am sharing my experience. If fully qualified URL path is not set, meaning `scheme+host+path+trailing slash` I was able to notice similar issues. Other thing you can check is browser cache: close all browser windows and try again but in private mode. That way you should be certain there ain't no caching pages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161821/discussion-between-stefan-stankovic-and-tpojka).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add base_url before the script and css files. and specify the folder in which is kept.Like we have style.css file in assets/css folder

```
<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css'); ?>
Or 
<?php echo base_url().'assets/css/style.css'; ?>
```

Comment: I tried that, it also adds the `user/` in front of it.

Comment: can u specify what the base_url ?

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/domain_name';`

Comment: That's correct . where u use it. can u show the code ?

Comment: I never reference it directly, it's automatically prepended to all my links.

Comment: OK, this seemed to work, but I had to change the base url, as @Tpojka helpfully suggested. The problem was in the link I was testing it on (it was broken).